Windows Server 2k16 System File Checker errors
I've a Windows 2k16 server (datacenter) running as a VM in VMware vSphere infrastructure. I've my custom applications installed on it along with certain security agents. The Windows updates for all VMs in the infrastructure are centrally managed through another software.
I've a periodic check scheduled for my VMs to check for system files and windows component store. For doing the same, I use following set of commands.

sfc /scannow to check and correct system files
dism /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth to scan if there are any issues with component store
disk /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth to correct if any errors are detected

During last few cycles, the sfc command is failing with error corrupt files detected but could not correct it. For such servers, the scanhealth also returns specifying component is repairable however, the restorehealth fails complaining about could not find Source.
From the CBS logs, I could find a lot of entries with either duplicate ownership for certain directories or no ownership at all [DIRSD OWNER WARNING]. Few sample log entries mentioned below
Info                  CSI    00002115 [DIRSD OWNER WARNING] Directory [l:69 ml:70]'??\C:\Windows\System32\ServerManagerInternal\ADDeploymentWF_Internal' is not owned but specifies SDDL in component Microsoft-ADRoles-Workflows-Common, arch amd64, nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}
2024-06-20 14:56:47, Info                  CSI    0000215f Error - Overlap: Duplicate ownership for directory ??\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Cem in component Microsoft-Foundation-Diagnostics-ErrorDetails, version 10.0.14393.5127, arch amd64, nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}
Searching through a lot of forums, these seem to be normal. I've followed suggestions in blogs for DIRSD and duplicate ownership. However, I still need help in confirming the following.

Is this normal condition or there is any risk to the running server in terms of Windows Updates?
Should there be a periodic remediation performed to correct these? Are the commands mentioned above sufficient as remediation or there's more to get the restorehealth complete without error.

Any pointers in right direction will be helpful.
